# How to insert a video in beamer using TexStudio/MikTex?

Tags: beamer, texstudio, miktex2.9, media9, multimedia

I am using TeXstudio/MiKTeX and Adobe Reader for my presentation.

I want to insert two videos in that, one in `.mov` and other in `.avi` formats. I saw many similar questions about problems with compilation but none of them solved my problem.

I cannot see the video in my presentation...

Sometimes I got problems with `PHONON=TRUE`. Other with Flash Player.

The last code I used was:

```latex
\begin{center}
        \includemedia[
        width=0.5\linewidth,
        activate=pageopen,
        addresource=example.mov,
        flashvars={
            source=example.mov
            &autoPlay=true
        },
        passcontext, % enable VPlayer's right-click menue
        ]{\includegraphics{example-movie}}{VPlayer.swf}%
    \end{center}
```

In all times, I just got a frame like this (a static picture):

[image]

or this:

[image]

Any suggestion wthat I need to do? Any help will be appreciated.